# Acessing activity data from custom button

Tags: android, button, custom-controls

In my Android activity I have created members which I want to access from my custom button created dynamically. Is there a mechanism to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your code and make better explaination for your problem

Comment: Explain more your problem..

Comment: post your code and  "access from" - pls explain with a higher precision!

Answer (score 0):

You can create interface:

```
interface SomeDataProvider {
    SomeData get();
}
```

Your activity (or activity member) should implement this interface. Then, in custom button class you will have the following:

```
public class CustomButton {
    private SomeDataProvider mDataProvider;

    public void setDataProvider(SomeDataProvider provider) {
        mDataProvider = provider;
    }
}
```

After creating custom button dynamically, you should call setDataProvider() method. But it is not safe to call CustomButton#mDataProvider.get() method after any long background action, because hosting activity could be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you wish to tackle this you could:

1. Set the current activity into your Application object (do so for onCreate, onResume) and provide a reference to your Application for every custom object constructor.
2. If you are creating the Custom Button from the activity, you could pass the Activity as a reference and ensure your members have proper getters/setters.